# performSegueWithIdentifier blocks UIAlertView and even [activityImageView startAnimating]

Tags: ios, uialertview, uistoryboardsegue

I want to start a wait animation/show UIAlertView before calling a segue so that the user will know they have to wait for a couple of seconds while the segue gets processed and the next ViewController gets populated with relevant data and shows up!

The problem is performSegueWithIdentifier prevents any kind of animation/UIAlertView to show up. Only after the segue finishes then the animations get their chance to popup!

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to implement your animation logic in the `prepareForSegue` method.  That method gets called and finished before the segue is executed.

Also, if this flow doesn't fit, fire off the performSegue method when the animation is over or the user responds to the UIAlertView that you have fired off.

OR if you haven't been using `MBProgressHUD`, take a look at that.  I use this when I am dealing with external data and want the user to know something is going on (getting data from a web-service).  It is easy and simple to implement.

Comment: Hi ElJay, how can I fire off the performSegue method when the animation is over? It's linked to a button and even though I put the content of prepareForSegue inside the block I can't make it wait until the animation finishes.  The segue continues as usual with the modal window.